# Java Step Builder with Conditional Steps

Tags: java, builder

I'm busy implementing Step Builders into a Java application and I've written some horrendous code. I'm quite certain I'm missing a necessary step.

For an example, I'll use the buildable class `Machine.java`

```
public class Machine {

    private String type;;
    private boolean mobile;
    private final String mobileType;

    public Machine(MachineBuilder builder) {
        this.type = builder.type;
        this.mobile = builder.mobile;
        this.mobileType = builder.mobileType;
    }

    public String getType() { return this.type; }
    public boolean getMobile() { return this.mobile; }
    public String getMobileType() { return this.mobileType; }

}
```

And the step builder for it as `MachineBuilder.java`

```
public class MachineBuilder {

    public String type;
    public boolean mobile;
    public String mobileType;

    public MachineBuilder() { }

    // initialize builder
    public Builder start() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    // interfaces
    public interface iType {
        iBuild withType(String type);
    }
    public interface iMobileType {
        iBuild withMobileType(String mobileType);
    }
    public interface iBuild {
        iMobileType withMobile();
        iBuild withMobileType(String mobileType);
        Machine build();
    }

    // subclass to return
    public static class Builder extends MachineBuilder implements iType, iMobileType, iBuild {

        public iBuild withType(String type) {
            super.type = type; return this;
        }
        public iMobileType withMobile() {
            super.mobile = true; return this;
        }
        public iBuild withMobileType(String mobileType) {
            super.mobileType = mobileType; return this;
        }
        public Machine build() {
            return new Machine(this);
        }

    }

}
```

The intention is to have `type` as a required step, then `mobile` as optional but if `mobile` is used then `mobileType` must be used as well.

It's only half working though

```
    // fine
    Machine car = new MachineBuilder()
        .start().withType("car").withMobile().withMobileType("driving").build();
    System.out.println(car.getType() + ":" + car.getMobile() + ":" + car.getMobileType());

    // fine
    Machine washingMachine = new MachineBuilder()
        .start().withType("washingMachine").build();
    System.out.println(washingMachine.getType() + ":" + washingMachine.getMobile() + ":" + washingMachine.getMobileType());

    // corrupt (no type)
    Machine boat = new MachineBuilder()
        .start().withMobile().withMobileType("sailing").build();
    System.out.println(boat.getType() + ":" + boat.getMobile() + ":" + boat.getMobileType());

    // corrupt (no anything)
    Machine bicycle = new MachineBuilder()
        .start().build();
    System.out.println(bicycle.getType() + ":" + bicycle.getMobile() + ":" + bicycle.getMobileType());
```

I had to initialize the builder object with the method `start` but this is not implementing any of the interfaces so just calling `start` then `build` will corrupt the object. Similarly calling the optional method for `mobile` allows it to bypass the `type`.

Is it possible to force flow direction from the start without using a `start` method at all? I feel like I am missing something very stupid.

PS. sorry for slapping so much code into the question I just wanted to illustrate the issue as best as I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thrill to answer this question. I try to rewrite your code. Just reorganize it following `Step Builder Pattern`'s strategy.

Add no description here, hope you can easily understand the code.

```
class Machine {
    private String type;
    private boolean isMobile;
    private String mobileType;

    public static TypeStep builder(){
        return new MachineBuilder();
    }
    
    public interface TypeStep{
        IsMobileStep withType(String type);
    }
    
    public interface IsMobileStep{
        MobileTypeStep withMobile(boolean isMobile);
        
    }
    
    public interface MobileTypeStep{
        Build withMobileType(String mobileType);
    }
    
    public interface Build{
        Machine build();
    }
    
    
    public static class MachineBuilder implements TypeStep, IsMobileStep, MobileTypeStep, Build {
        private String type;
        private boolean isMobile;
        private String mobileType;
        
        @Override
        public IsMobileStep withType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public MobileTypeStep withMobile(boolean isMobile) {
            this.isMobile = isMobile;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Build withMobileType(String mobileType) {
            this.mobileType = mobileType;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Machine build() {
            return new Machine(this);
        }
        
    }
    
    private Machine(MachineBuilder machineBuilder) {
        this.type = machineBuilder.type;
        this.isMobile = machineBuilder.isMobile;
        this.mobileType = machineBuilder.mobileType;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public boolean isMobile() {
        return isMobile;
    }

    public String getMobileType() {
        return mobileType;
    }
}
```

Test run:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine car = Machine.builder().withType("car").withMobile(true).withMobileType("driving").build();
        
        System.out.println("Model 1:"+ car.getType() +":"+ car.isMobile()+":"+car.getMobileType());
        
        Machine boat = Machine.builder().withType("boat").withMobile(true).withMobileType("driving").build();
        
        System.out.println("Model 2:"+ boat.getType() +":"+ boat.isMobile()+":"+boat.getMobileType());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Model 1:car:true:driving
Model 2:boat:true:driving
```

For better readability: [Github Repo Step Builder](https://github.com/khabib97/StackOverflow-Responses/tree/main/StepBuilderPattern)

Comment: Thank you so much for your enthusiasm! This answer was just what I needed and I'm really grateful that you stuck to the interface method, the starting point `builder` returning the `TypeStep` interface was the thing that got me sorted, thanks a bunch and all the best

Answer (score 1):

I think your builder implementation is very difficult and not very correct.
The typical builder should have private constructors, initial methods, field setters and build methods. I would do so:

```
public class MachineBuilder  {

    public String type;

    public boolean mobile;

    public String mobileType;

    private MachineBuilder (final String type, final boolean mobile, final String mobileType) {
        this.type = type;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.mobileType = mobileType;
    }
    
    private MachineBuilder(){
        
    }

    public MachineBuilder setType(final String source) {
        this.type = source;
        return this;
    }

    public MachineBuilder setMobile(final boolean source) {
        this.mobile = source;
        return this;
    }

    public MachineBuilder setMobileType(final String source) {
        this.mobileType = source;
        return this;
    }

    public static MachineBuilder init() {
        return new MachineBuilder();
    }

    public static MachineBuilder init(final String type, final boolean mobile, final String mobileType) {
        return new MachineBuilder(type, mobile, mobileType);
    }

    public MachineBuilder build() {  
        return Machine(this.type, this.mobile, this.mobileType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dmitrii, I use this approach for standard builders but for this I'm asking more about step builders, with sequence forcing and required/optional compile time errors